# Finding shortest list that contains all letters from a specific list of words. (Pangrams)

Tags: python, word-list, pangram

I'm trying to find the fewest amount of words in a list that would make a Pangram. I.E contains all letters of the alphabet.

I can find words that contain a certain amount of letters that I've taken from another post but if I was looking for the fewest words from that list I would need to contain all letters of the alphabet how would I go about it.

This is where I am at the moment:

```
wordlist = ['mississipi','miss','lake','que']

letters = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

for word in wordlist:
    if letters & set(word):
        print word
```

Any help would be great, 
Thanks

Comment: in your example no amount of words is enough. there is no `z` anywhere for example..

Comment: Hint: construct *combinations* of words.

Comment: This was more of example words. In reality I’d have a larger amount of words that would contain all the letters of the alphabet